# Android Facebook Registercallback not called

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am using facebook login into my application. Now I am facing one strange issue in my project LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback not getting called.

I am using following codes:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());//It showing as deprecated now
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity());//It showing as deprecated now
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

muvattapuzha

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        System.out.println("eeeee");
                        // App code
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                        // Application code not called

                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,gender");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();

                    }
```

OnActivity result method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Note: I am using with Activity->fragment-> fragment.

Activity onResult method like

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                for (Fragment fragment1 : fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                    fragment1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    Log.d("Activity", "ON RESULT CALLED");
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Please share how you are adding fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this is working fine for me.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

          @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LoginMainActivity.this);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_main);  

            loginButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_btn_login);
                loginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb_rounded_broder);
                loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
                loginButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
                loginButton.setText("");
                loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "user_birthday", "user_hometown"}));
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User login successfully");

                        getProfile();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                        Log.d(TAG, "User cancel login");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Log.d(TAG, "Problem for login");
                    }
                });



            public void getProfile() {

                    try {
                        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                accessToken,
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Graph Object :" + object);
                                        try {
                                            String[] splitStr = object.getString("name").split("\\s+");
                                            FBFirstname = splitStr[0];
                                            FBLastName = splitStr[1];
                                            FBEmail = object.getString("email");
                                            FBUUID = object.getString("id");
                                            Log.e(TAG, "firstnamev: " + splitStr[0]);
                                            Log.e(TAG, "last name: " + splitStr[1]);
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Email id : " + object.getString("email"));
                                            Log.e(TAG, "ID :" + object.getString("id"));

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,gender,email");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // Result returned from launching the Intent from 

              {
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is difference from my question?

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0' are you using this facebook gradle?

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0' using this one

Comment: check new code this is working fine for me in my app.

Comment: callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LoginMainActivity.this); on where put this code??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192319/discussion-between-mayur-panchal-and-amsheer).